# Mule choice route depending on payload type ie object type?

Tags: mule

I have route choice depending on the payload. The payload can be either list, map or string. The payload has to be identified and routed depending on the payload type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you want something like that

```
<choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[payload is List]">
            <logger level="INFO" message="i am list" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </when>
        <when expression="#[payload is Map]">
            <logger level="INFO" message="i am map" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </when>
        <when expression="#[payload is String]">
            <logger level="INFO" message="i am string" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise> 
            <logger message="class doesnt match with [list, map, string]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>  
        </otherwise>  
    </choice>
```

Answer (score 4):

I do agree with Eddú response, except for that I would add an `otherwise` path. If you don't do that and get something different than a list map or string you would get the rather cryptic error:

`org.mule.api.routing.RoutePathNotFoundException: Can't process message because no route has been found matching any filter and no default route is defined. Failed to route event via endpoint: ChoiceRouter [flow-construct=testNull, started=true]. Message payload is of type: NullPayload`